# react state change doesn't re-render?

Tags: reactjs

this is my state

```
const [task,setTask] = useState(
{
  _id:"z"
  name:"Test",
  description:"TestTestTest",
  status:false,
  sub_task:[
  {
    name:"TestSub",
    description:"TestSub",
    status:false,
  }
]
}
)

 const test = e =>{
    if(task._id=== "z"){
      let check = e.target.checked
      let sub = task.sub_task.slice();
      if(check) sub.forEach(el => el.status= check);
      setSelTask({...task,status:check,sub_task:sub})
    }else{
      setSelTask({...task,status:check})
    }
  }
```

what it should hange is the checked property of an input type checkbox that looks like this

```
 task.sub_task.map(item=>{
  return (
  <input     
        type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={item.status}
        onChange={onChange}
        className=" absolute"
      />
)
})
```

but it's not changing...after reading some other answers similar to this i thought that the problem was because i was passing the array by reference but i tried different things like JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) but it's not working

Comment: Where is`onChange`?

Answer (score 1):

You had a few typo and you were calling the wrong function:
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-cartwright-swcmo